# JSON to Features geoprocessing tool fails when creating SQL Server feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, geoprocessing, json, arcgis-10.4

For some reason the "JSON to Features" geoprocessing tool thinks the schema name is the table name and therefore always fails. Seems like it may be a software bug.  Anyone else have this problem?

*ERROR 000206: Cannot create FeatureClass 'Database Connections\AP_dbo@server.sde\AP.DBO.Networks_json'. Table already exists [42S01:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'DBO' in the database.] **[AP.AP.DBO]***

Where "AP" is the DB name and "DBO" is the schema. It should be naming the feature class: "AP.DBO.Networks_json"

SQL Server 2012
ArcGIS 10.4.1

Comment: I can reproduce this here at Esri, checking with the team about logging a bug or what else it could be. As a workaround for now, Output JSON to Features to a local FGDB, then use copy features to insert into your SQL Server

Comment: Given that the output table cannot be created in other than the connected database and owned by other than the connected user,  have you tried removing "AP.DBO." from the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been informed this has been logged as **BUG-000088916 - The JSON To Features tool fails with the error, "DBMS table not found" when converting JSON to an Enterprise Geodatabase feature class.**

We (esri) are investigating it. As for a workaround, direct the output to a local fGDB and then use a tool like Copy Features to move the output into the enterprise geodatabase.